# Alternative to PHP "goto output;"

Tags: php, wordpress, goto

I use a plugin for WordPress that uses "goto output;" which causes problems for some friends of mine who use PHP 5.3. They would also like to use the plugin I found, called MiniPress.

How could this plugin be re-written so it would work in PHP 5.3?

```
private static function get_filesystem() {
    if ( false === self::$fs ) {
        global $wp_filesystem;

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

        $write_method = get_filesystem_method( array(), false );
        if ( $write_method != 'direct' && $write_method != 'ftpsockets' ) {
            self::$fs = false;
            goto output;
        }

        if ( false === ( $creds = @request_filesystem_credentials( '' ) ) ) {
            self::$fs = false;
            goto output;
        }

        if ( ! WP_Filesystem( $creds ) ) {
            self::$fs = false;
            goto output;
        }

        self::$fs = $wp_filesystem;
    }

    output:
    return self::$fs;
}
```

p.s :  I'm not the author of the plugin

Comment: Jesus. `goto` in PHP. Why on earth?

Comment: I didn't write the code... It's not my plugin. I was just wondering if someone could rewrite it though, because it causes some problems for my friends who use PHP 5.3.

Comment: @Adam I'd be very wary of using _any_ code from whoever wrote that

Comment: @Clive, the plugin works very, very well for me and my wordpress installation. I don't like goto either, but I DIDN'T WRITE THE PLUGIN and forgot how to write PHP as well as I used to, so I wouldn't know how to rewrite it.

Comment: I didn't say you did, I said you should be wary of using code from anyone who _does_ use `goto` in this manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
private static function get_filesystem() {
    if ( false === self::$fs ) {
        global $wp_filesystem;

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

        $write_method = get_filesystem_method( array(), false );
        if ( $write_method != 'direct' && $write_method != 'ftpsockets' ) {
            self::$fs = false;
        }

        else if ( false === ( $creds = @request_filesystem_credentials( '' ) ) ) {
            self::$fs = false;
        }

        else if ( ! WP_Filesystem( $creds ) ) {
            self::$fs = false;
        } else self::$fs = $wp_filesystem;
    }

    return self::$fs;
}
```

Comment: This works even better and seems to cause the process to run faster. Very good.

Comment: @Adam, "seems to cause the process to run faster", yeah I feel that 1ms of gain too.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace:

```
goto output;
```

with:

```
return self::$fs;
```

and delete `output:` at the end.

Your method can then be rewritten as:

```
private static function get_filesystem() {
    if ( false === self::$fs ) {
        global $wp_filesystem;
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        $write_method = get_filesystem_method( array(), false );
        if (
            ($write_method != 'direct' && $write_method != 'ftpsockets') || 
            (false === ($creds = @request_filesystem_credentials(''))) ||
            (!WP_Filesystem($creds))
        ) self::$fs = false;
        else self::$fs = $wp_filesystem;
    }
    return self::$fs;
}
```

Comment: My friends said it worked! Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Jueecy  If you change the inner conditional to set `self::$fs = $wp_filesystem` when all the (inverted) conditions are true, only the last `return` is needed, giving even further simplification.`

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
private static function get_filesystem() {
    if ( false === self::$fs ) {
        global $wp_filesystem;

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

        $write_method = get_filesystem_method( array(), false );

        if ( 
            $write_method != 'direct' && $write_method != 'ftpsockets' 
            ||
            false === ( $creds = @request_filesystem_credentials( '' ) )
            ||
            ! WP_Filesystem( $creds )
        ) {
            self::$fs = false;
        } else {
            self::$fs = $wp_filesystem;
        }
    } 
    return self::$fs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all redundant code, you end up with this:

```
private static function get_filesystem() {
    if ( false === self::$fs ) {
        global $wp_filesystem;
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        $write_method = get_filesystem_method( array(), false );
        if (($write_method == 'direct' || $write_method == 'ftpsockets') && 
            (false !== ($creds = @request_filesystem_credentials(''))) &&
            (WP_Filesystem($creds)) {
          self::$fs = $wp_filesystem;
        }
    }
    return self::$fs;
}
```